# Can I enter 1 week and a half before expiration of I-94?

Tags: mexican-citizens

I have a tn visa and I'm planning to travel to Mexico for christmas and I would be returning in January. My I-94 expires 12 days after.

I'm planning in applying for an extension (I-129) one day after returning to the USA. Supposedly I won't be out of status if I have an application pending. Will I have any problems entering the country with immigration officers?

Would it be better to apply for a new visa at a US consulate, or extension is good enough.

Thanks

Comment: As I understand it you'll get a new period of admission when you return, not be readmitted for the remaining 12 days of your current admission.  Getting a new visa won't help and isn't necessary.  Of course it is a good idea to keep your visa valid to facilitate travel on short notice, so if your visa is expiring soon you should probably renew it for the sake of flexibility.